# How to get specific data from database when using search input box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one live search box. Here I am populating some records while searching in the search box.

`search.php` looks like:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  // Fetch result rows as an associative array
  $output .= '
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table style="background-color: darkgray;margin-bottom: 0px !important;" class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  ';

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $row[] = $r;
    $output .= '
      <tr>
      <td data-name='.$empID.' data-age='.$empAge.'>'.$row["empName"].'</td>
      <td data-name='.$empID.' data-age='.$empAge.'>'.$row["joinDate"].'</td>
      </tr>
    ';
  }  echo $output;
}
```

Here am facing a problem.When data-name attribute is null inspect shows the td like

```
<td data-name="data-age=20"></td>
```

why the data-name value is concatenate with next attribute?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's hard to tell what you're asking. It's best to post parts of your code that will look familiar to others, and it's hard to tell what's happening in your code. Could you narrow down your question to a part of the code that isn't working?

Comment: "I need to" isn't a question. "how to" is too vague, there could be many possible ways, in a broad sense. What have you tried to do in relation to your requirement? What problem are you facing when you try to code it? What specifically do you need us to help you with?

Comment: how to get details of the particular data [from the search results i am going to select only one data but i want to get others details of the particular data]

Comment: can any one please help me?

Comment: you've just repeated what you wrote in the question. Obviously, if we didn't understand it the first time we won't understand it the second time either. You need to clarify your meaning and actually ask a proper question, please. Re-read my earlier comment, and also please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for further guidance. I'm sorry to have to say this but right now it's not possible to help you because we don't know what your exact problem is.

Comment: actually in my web page one live search box and two input box is there.when searching a name in the search box all the details will give(fetching from db) and from the datas am going to select one data.In this data how i fetch other data from the selected data?

Comment: for example,when am start to search a name it will display name based on the name i need to fetch id age of the particular name to the input field.Here how i pass datas to javascript?

Comment: here is code how i keep datas in the same td in this i need to store emp_age and emp_company <td >'.$row["empName"].'</td> then only while clicking the td i will get details of the particular data and autopopulate to input field.

Comment: <td >'.$row["empName"].'</td><td >'.$row["joinDate"].'</td>                                
 this listed table row is clickable for example it is listing 4 records.Now am going to select 3rd record .how i get the emp_id for the particular employee name that is my question.

Comment: please add that code in the question, not comments. Use the "edit" button to change your question. It's hard to read here. But thanks for giving more info

Comment: Anyway it seems that you're trying to read the data from "data-" attributes `$(this).attr('data-name')` but based on what you've just shown me and also your PHP code, your HTML doesn't contain any such attributes. So maybe you simply need to add them.

Comment: already i give the code in search.php.See the while loop function.there am created a table for listing the data (when user start to search table will show next to the seach box)

Comment: yeah i used data attributes in the "<td>".but the problem is when the data is null its simply showing the attribute name  in the input field.Thats why am asking any other solution is there or?

Comment: In `$(this).attr('data-name')`, `$(this)` is the clicked `.result td`. In the rows returned by `search.php`, there is no data attribute at all.

Comment: i gave like this <td data-name='.$empID.' data-id='.$empAge.' >'.$row["empName"].'</td> and am getting the value when clicking the td.But the problem is when data-name is null its showing wrong.if data-name is null value its just showing <td data-name="data-id=20">angel</td> and printing the value in input box like data-age=20.I just want to show input filed blank

Comment: Could you edit your question with that part? Make sure it's your real used code... Because I think you typed it by heart just above... And you are "mixing" `name`, `id` and `age`...

Comment: yeah i have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are missing the double quotes `"`, needed on client side, for the data attributes.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $row[] = $r;
  $output .= '
    <tr>
    <td data-name="'.$empID.'" data-age="'.$empAge.'">'.$row["empName"].'</td>
    <td data-name="'.$empID.'" data-age="'.$empAge.'">'.$row["joinDate"].'</td>
    </tr>
  ';
}  echo $output;
```

The single quotes `'` are string delimiter used on PHP side in the while loop to produces the HTML markup of a `tr`. In that markup, the data attributes are strings too... And need to be wrapped... That's were the double quotes `"` are needed.

Comment: is there any other way for storing many datas. Bcoz its a large form i feel difficult to fetch each data to the particular input..In my form lots of input fields are there.Can u plz help me out of this?

Comment: Then I suggest you to only store the employee id in a data attribute. And on click, make an Ajax request, using that id, to fetch all the data related to that particular entry.

Comment: but HTML form is in another page called index.php when user start to search ajax url to search.php have this fetching data from db.Can u plz tell me how can i get it through javascript using this id?

Comment: *«form is in another page»*... mmm. There too many thing I don't know about what you try to achieve. What I understood is that on search, you get a table of matching results... Then you click one. From there, you should make an [Ajax request](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html) to fetch all the data of this entry. -- Sorry, but this is real not easy to answer to this. You have to read about ajax... That is my best advise.